# How to better add input fields dynamically with wtfforms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'd like to compose Form fields in code, dynamically, according to the type of data.

I have *app.py* file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, FormField, FieldList

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretomucho'

class StringForm(FlaskForm):
    string = StringField()

class IntegerForm(FlaskForm):
    integer = IntegerField()
    
class EntriesForm(FlaskForm):
    strings = FieldList(FormField(StringForm))
    integers = FieldList(FormField(IntegerForm))

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    strs = [{"string": "First String"}, {"string": "Second String"}]
    ints = [{"integer": 1}, {"integer": 2}]
    form = EntriesForm(strings=strs, integers=ints)
                
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

and *index.html* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% for field in form %}
            <td> {{ field.label }} </td>
            <td> {{ field }} </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Which produces:

[image: results]

But I'd like to have a less grouped look, types of values mixed up, maybe some sections with different data types that can be toggled, etc. All that composed in code according to different data structures.

Something like:

```
form = MyForm()
form.addIntegerField(value)
form.addStringField(value2)
form.addIntegerField(value3)
return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve that with https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/specific_problems/#dynamic-form-composition

The key was to use an internal subclass:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField,

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretomucho'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    
    class MyForm(FlaskForm):
        pass
    
    setattr(MyForm, 'test1', StringField('StringField 1'))
    setattr(MyForm, 'test2', IntegerField('IntegerField 1'))
    setattr(MyForm, 'test3', IntegerField('IntegerField 2'))
    setattr(MyForm, 'test4', StringField('StringField 2'))
    
    form = MyForm()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```